# Active Record Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, schema, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to achieve the following, relationships and object calls and wondering if I need a separate table and how those associations would work.

A User can leave many notes (user.notes) A Note can have one Sender (note.sender)

A User can receive many notes (user.notes). A Note can have many receivers (notes.recipient).  A Note can be viewed_at by a recipient.

A user can select a recipient.
A user can select many recipients.

A recipient can view each note once.
Once all the recipients of the note have viewed the note the note will be destroyed.

My schema looks like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first
      t.string :last
      t.string :email
      t.string :username
      t.string :pw
      t.string :devicetoken

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notes do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :recipient_id
      t.text :note_text
      t.datetime: viewed_at
      t.datetime :expiration

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My Models Look Like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'recipient_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

I can't pull up the recipient ids of the notes however, and I can't tell which recipient have viewed the note.

Comment: How are you trying to access the recipient ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're having trouble because you are defining two belongs_to for the same symbol. Try doing this instead:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: 'recipient_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

Then try calling `note.recipient`

Comment: Thank you!  What about determining which recipient has viewed the note? Is that a separate table?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean - Can somebody other than the recipient view the note?

Comment: The idea is the note can only be viewed once so the get request won't retrieve notes that have already been viewed by the recipient.  IN the case of multiple recipients the note would be destroyed once all recipients had viewed it.

Comment: in that case, your current definition of note has a 1:1 relationship with recipient, so you'll probably want to create a new table for recipients that contains the note_id and the user:id of the recipient. You can add a flag to that table that gets marked when read, and then create a scope `:unread_notes` that checks for this flag and only returns the records without the flag set.

Comment: Thanks Alec, regarding the controller `:unread_notes` scope where would that live

Comment: Also, would the Note object have a recipient field or does the object get that automatically from the associated Recipients Table?